# compiling make -f makefile.win failed on windows 7

Tags: r, rcpp, rinside

I am a Chinese scholar with a strong interest in calling R function via RInside. I followed general instructions to install R, RCPP, RInside, and Rtools under `C:\R\R-3.3.0`. My OS is Windows 7. When I using the Windows command prompt to run `make -f makefile.win`, the compile fails. I got some errors :

```
C:\R\R-3.2.0\example>make -f makefile.win
' | /bin/R --arch  --vanilla --slave) ' | /bin/R --arch  --vanilla --slave)  -Wa
ll  -s  rinside.cpp     '  | /bin/R --arch  --vanilla --slave) '  | /bin/R --arc
h  --vanilla --slave) -o rinside
Syntax error: ")" unexpected
make: *** [rinside] Error 2
```

I also used to Cygwin to run `make -f makefile.win` and got almost the same error as below:

```
gtang@5c260a55ee19 /cygdrive/c/r/r-3.2.0/example
$ make -f makefile.win
' | /bin/R --arch  --vanilla --slave) ' | /bin/R --arch  --vanilla --slave)  -Wall  -s  rinside.cpp     '  | /bin/R --arch  --vanilla --slave) '  | /bin/R --arch  --vanilla --slave) -o rinside
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `' | /bin/R --arch  --vanilla --slave) ' | /bin/R --arch  --vanilla --slave)  -Wall  -s  rinside.cpp     '  | /bin/R --arch  --vanilla --slave) '  | /bin/R --arch  --vanilla --slave) -o rinside'
<builtin>: recipe for target `rinside' failed
make: *** [rinside] Error 1
```

How should I fix this issue? Should I use another Unix shell instead of bash to run `make -f makefile.win`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't regularly build RInside on Windows but I have done so repeatedly. It generally works, and it doesn't this usually means that you setup in incorrect.

Seeing how you use Cygwin in the second part of your question I *strongly* suggest you re-read the pertinent sections of [R Installation and Administration](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html) -- particularly those pertaining to `PATH` etc.  Cygwin was never supported by R, and having Cygwin commands in your `PATH` is generally just a recipe for tears...